# How to check if cronjob ran in ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-16.04

I am absolutely new to `ubuntu` and `cron`.

I want to run some scripts:

I edited and saved the `crontab` file:

`37 13 30 6 * /media/xxx/xxx/bin/python /home/xxx/PycharmProjects/testcron.py`

`testcron.py` code:

```
print('Hellow World')
input('Test Success')
```

I assumed that this would show me if the `cronjob` ran.

But no window popped up on the time I set.

Can someone point me to how to check if it ran? Did I configure this wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you haven't done anything on your system, try looking in

```
/var/log/syslog
```

Use grep to filter/search:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

You can also pipe the output of your cron job to a specific location as well

```
37 13 30 6 * /media/xxx/xxx/bin/python /home/xxx/PycharmProjects/testcron.p >> /var/log/job.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks. :) The cron job ran, here is the output: >Jun 30 13:17:01 CRON[19777]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 30 13:37:01  CRON[20874]:  CMD (/media/xxx/xxx/bin/python /home/xxx/PycharmProjects/testcron.py)
Jun 30 13:37:01 CRON[20873]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output). No MTA installed?

Comment: Linux will uses mail system for sending notifications to the user. MTA = Mail Transfer Agent. Ubuntu doesn't have one by default as far as I know. So to resolve that, you could install one. e.g. issue the command ""sudo apt-get install postfix" (there are various MTAs) However if you don't want to bother installed an MTA, then the second option outlined above should resolve that for you. Just pipe the output to a known location.

Answer (score 4):

I always include `date >> ~/cronjobname.txt` at the end of my cron job scripts. It will keep appending the date and time to that text file every time it runs. Another advantage to this is, If someone runs it manually for any reason (testing, debugging), you will have that timestamp too.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can create a `testcron.py` file that looks like this:

```py
f = open("cool_test", "w")
f.write("")
f.close()
```

If you run `python3 testcron.py`, you'll see a `cool_test` file generated in the same directory as `testcron.py`.

Now, you can just call `testcron.py` from a cronjob, and you'll be able to verify the process worked by making sure that `cool_file` was generated.